# Looking to protect enchantment in Mono Black

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I recently aquired the Necron precon commander deck. Played it a couple of times, works pretty great out of the box. One of the better cards in the deck is [Out of the Tombs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=580868). Really gives a great edge when your library is empty and you can just mess around with stuff in your graveyard. Of course, counterplays could be exiling the graveyard or destroying the enchantment when there are no more cards in your library, making you lose the game.

So I'm looking for ways to protect this enchantment. Give it hexproof/shroud, indestructible, protection from X etc. will all work fine. However, I cannot seem to find cards that do this in Mono Black or Colorless. Are there such cards?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "How do I do a thing with a colour that isn't designed to do that thing" is a common thought that (newer) Magic players have. The real answer is typically to accept that the colour can't do that and not build decks with a weakness that requires that thing, or use the workarounds the colour provides. It's also not typically a good idea to build your deck too much around 1 card (unless you also have other high-value enchantments you want to protect).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

1. **Counterspells.**  [Black/Colorless have a very small handful of these](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22counter+target%22+commander%3Ablack), and none is a slam dunk, but [Dash Hopes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dash%20Hopes), [Null Brooch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Null%20Brooch), or [Not of This World](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Not%20of%20This%20World) can all be good.
2. **Discard.**  Black has a lot of [targeted discard](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Areveal%20o%3Adiscard%20commander%3Ablack) ([Duress](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Duress) or [Inquisition of Kozilek](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Inquisition%20of%20Kozilek) are key examples) but it's almost all sorcery speed, so it doesn't protect you from enchantment destruction that they draw and play same turn.  If you want to go this route, you need to combine it with cards that will filter the deck too, like [Praetor's Grasp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Praetor%27s%20Grasp), [The Stone Brain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Stone%20Brain), [Surgical Extraction](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Surgical%20Extraction) or [Extirpate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Extirpate) (the last two really only work outside of Commander).
3. **Indestructible/Regenerate.**  [Renegade's Getaway](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Renegade%27s%20Getaway) is the simplest way to do this (credit to [@JonTheMon](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/58425/9999)), but there are more expensive or complex routes too like [Soul of New Phyrexia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20of%20New%20Phyrexia), [Liquimetal Coating](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liquimetal%20Coating) + [Welding Jar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Welding%20Jar) or [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice) + [Darksteel Forge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Forge).
4. **Play a second copy of the enchantment.**  Note: this only helps outside of commander, but the other cards that support this are ones you may want to have anyways.  In the case of Out of the Tombs in particular, you may not want to have two copies running simultaneously, so you need some way to not lose the game when your library is empty so that you can get past your draw step to play a second copy.  Also skipping draws can be helpful to not lose the game when your graveyard runs out (the lose condition printed on Out of the Tombs) .  [Words of Waste](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Words%20of%20Waste) is your best option here, but there is also [Platinum Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel) if your mana base can support it.
5. **Have a backup plan.**  If your key enchantment dies, you need some way to recover.  [Elixir of Immortality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elixir%20of%20Immortality) is your best bet for coming back from Out of the Tombs, but there are a bunch of cards that do [a similar same thing](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22graveyard%20into%22%20t%3Aartifact).

Comment: 1. OP didn't really specify the format but did mention Commander, so it might be worth noting that multiple copies are not legal there. 3.Even instant speed discard wouldn't guarantee to save your enchantment, because card draw happens after upkeep and opponent gets main phase priority first.

Comment: @Hackworth I added a note for commander.  Instant speed discard can still stop the opponent from playing sorcery speed cards, as players get priority during the draw step.

Answer (score 7):

I can only find one card that does this:

- [Renegade's Getaway](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Renegade%27s%20Getaway)

Found it by searching Scryfall for a black card in commander that's an instant that gives indestructible.

For other ways to keep the enchantment on the battlefield (sorta):

- [Synod Sanctum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Synod%20Sanctum)
- [Gerrard's Hourglass Pendant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gerrard%27s%20Hourglass%20Pendant)

Answer (score 2):

**No, mono-black has no good options to protect enchantments in any format.**

Black is mostly about hand, graveyard, and creature interaction. Preventing spells and enters-the-battlefield effects is basically impossible unless you make the opponent discard those cards before they cast them, which is only a limited form of protection. Black specializes in returning creatures to the hand/battlefield, but returning other permanent types is much rarer.

Protecting enchantments specifically is notoriously difficult in any color. Blue would be the best option, but only due to generic control and disruption (counterspells). Indestructible is, without very specific combos, mostly limited to creatures and artifacts, and protection even more so. The best options to grant something hexproof are in green and white.